# CloudFormation SecretTargetAttachment return SecretString is not valid JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a simple CloudFormation Stack, but it does not work. Here is my CloudFormation template.

```
Resources:
  MyDBSecrets:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties: 
      Description: 'This is password of mysql database'
      GenerateSecretString:
        PasswordLength: 16
        ExcludePunctuation: true
      Name: MyDBSecrets
  MyDBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: MyDBInstance
      AllocatedStorage: '20'
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
      Engine: mysql
      MasterUsername: 'testdb'
      MasterUserPassword: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref MyDBSecrets, ':SecretString}}' ]]
  SecretRDSInstanceAttachment:
    Type: "AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment"
    Properties:
      SecretId: !Ref MyDBSecrets
      TargetId: !Ref MyDBInstance
      TargetType: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
```

On stack creation I can see my secrect resource is created, my RDS instance is also created, but on  SecretTargetAttachment I am getting `CREATE_FAILED with 'SecretString is not valid JSON'` error. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

Secrets Manager typically store secrets in one of two formats:

- as part of a JSON object `{ "user": "master", "password": "password123" }`
- or as a plain test secret, e.g. `password123`

The Secrets Manager documentation recommends the JSON version, and their samples all use it. In CloudFormation this can be generated using `SecretStringTemplate`, and a password  field (for example) can be extracted using `:SecretText:password` after the secret ARN in a dynamic field interpolation.

Furthermore this format appears to be required by `AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment` as it stores the RDS instance in another field in the JSON object.  This is the cause of your error.

A word of warning if you are using this with ECS: you should not use a dynamic interpolation in the Task Definition as this will be saved in plain text for anyone to read from the console/cli.  Instead you should use a Secrets section with a `ValueFrom` the secrets manager.  This, unfortunately, does not currently appear to support extracting fields from the JSON blob.  Instead you will have to parse the JSON blob within your docker container.

Comment: Regarding ECS Task Definition, it appears that this feature is now supported. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html

Answer (score 1):

Reference Pattern for **Secrets Manager** secrets, the reference-key segment is composed of several segments, including the secret id, secret value key, version stage, and version id.

Use the following pattern:`{{resolve:secretsmanager:secret-id:secret-string:json-key:version-stage:version-id}}`

**secret-id**: The name or Amazon Resource Name (ARN) that serves as a unique identifier for the secret.To access a secret in your AWS account, you need only specify the secret name. To access a secret in adifferent AWS account, specify the complete ARN of the secret.Required.

**secret-string**: Currently, the only supported value is SecretString. The default is SecretString.

**json-key**: Specifies the key name of the key-value pair whose value you want to retrieve. If you do not specifya json-key, CloudFormation retrieves the entire secret text.This segment may not include the colon character ( : ).

**version-stage**: Specifies the secret version that you want to retrieve by the staging label attached to the version.Staging labels are used to keep track of different versions during the rotation process. If you use version-stage then don't specify version-id. If you don't specify either a version stage or aversion ID, then the default is to retrieve the version with the version stage value of AWSCURRENT.This segment may not include the colon character ( : ).

**version-id**: Specifies the unique identifier of the version of the secret that you want to use in stack operations.If you specify version-id, then don't specify version-stage. If you don't specify either a versionstage or a version ID, then the default is to retrieve the version with the version stage value ofAWSCURRENT.This segment may not include the colon character ( : ).

For more info go [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-ug.pdf).

Comment: I tried all possible options specified here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html, You might have noticed my secret is a plain text and  my guess is somehow this issue is related to 'AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment'

Comment: When is apply my secret directly without SecretRDSInstanceAttachment it works

Comment: That's not the correct answer to my question I would like to know why do I get that exception.

Comment: @YasirAli, because the association only works with json.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem it was not straightforward. I contacted to AWS support team and they helped me to resolve it. AWS support team recommended using macros for custom processing on template.

Step1 : Macro.yml

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  TransformExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: ['logs:*']
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: ['s3:*']
                Resource: '*'
  TransformFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
            import traceback
            def handler(event, context):
                response = {
                    "requestId": event["requestId"],
                    "status": "success"
                }
                try:
                    paramPassword= event["params"]["paramPassword"]
                    Description= event["fragment"]["Description"]
                    Name= event["fragment"]["Name"]
                    print(event)
                    print("starting macro execution")
                    fragment = {}
                    fragment['Name'] = Name
                    fragment['Description'] = Description
                    if paramPassword == "":
                      fragment['GenerateSecretString'] = {}
                      fragment['GenerateSecretString']['PasswordLength'] = 16
                      fragment['GenerateSecretString']['ExcludePunctuation'] = 'true'
                    else:
                      fragment['SecretString'] = {}
                      fragment['SecretString']['Ref'] = "paramPassword"
                    print(fragment)
                    response["fragment"] = fragment
                    print(response)
                except Exception:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    response["status"] = "failure"
                    macro_response["errorMessage"] = str(e)
                return response
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Role: !GetAtt TransformExecutionRole.Arn
  TransformFunctionPermissions:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt TransformFunction.Arn
      Principal: 'cloudformation.amazonaws.com'
  Transform:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Macro
    Properties:
      Name: 'SecretManager'
      Description: To check for secret's default value and conditionally create secret
      FunctionName: !GetAtt TransformFunction.Arn
```

Step 2: template.yml

```
Parameters:
  paramPassword:
    Type: String
    Default: test
    Description: Enter the default value of SecretString
Resources:
  LambdaIAMRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:*'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
Resources:
  TestSecrets:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:    
      'Fn::Transform':
            - Name: SecretManager
              Parameters:
                paramPassword: !Ref paramPassword
      Description: 'This is my password'
      Name: 'my-secret-password2'
```